Concordância: "a gente está preparada"ou "a gente está preparado"?
"O trabalho é mais fácil quando a gente está preparado." Já ouvi frases assim muitas vezes, mas "a gente" é substantivo feminino.  Então o predicativo do sujeito deveria concordar com o sujeito, não é?  Então o gramatical seria dizer "quando a gente está preparada".  Qual é o certo e por quê?  Obrigado.

Claro, você tem razão em relação ao feminino. Essa pergunta vindo de alguém que fala português me surpreende um pouco. Só que falta o subjuntivo: quando a gente esteja ou estiver preparada.  A menina está pronta para sair.  A gente, preparado, não.

Interessante, eu não sabia que há pessoas que usam o masculino com "a gente", mas vejo na Internet que estes erros (ou usos alternativos?) existem. Pensei que era igual a "a criança" e "uma pessoa".

@DanGetz Não é "alternativo" e muito menos erro. :-D

O  Priberam diz isso: a gente
• [Informal] Locução que corresponde semanticamente ao pronome pessoal nós, mas gramaticalmente a uma terceira pessoa do singular, e que designa o grupo em que se integra quem fala ou escreve (ex.: a gente vai chegar atrasada). Assim eu entendo o assunto.
"gente", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/gente.

Em poucas palavras
Usa-se:

"a gente está preparado", quando equivalente a "eu/nós estou/estamos preparado(s)"; e
"a gente está preparada", quando equivalente a "eu/nós estou/estamos preparada(s)".

Explicação
O ponto é que "a gente" não é um substantivo, é um pronome. Conferir, por exemplo, Jessé Mourão (note contudo que a aplicabilidade do que ele afirma ao pt-PT é questionável):

Há atualmente uma concepção bem consensual de que a expressão a gente no português brasileiro e europeu, como nos exemplos 8a e 8b [a gente faz; a gente fazemos], sofreu um processo de gramaticalização e já é considerado um pronome pessoal de primeira pessoa do plural equivalente ao pronome nós, e não um sintagma nominal formado por determinante e substantivo.

O "a gente" tem dois significados básicos:

nós / eu
pessoa genérica (como "one" em inglês, e.g., "One should be careful.")

Ou, como colocado pelo Houaiss:

a gente (1871)
1 a pessoa que fala; eu
2 a pessoa que fala em nome de si própria e de outro(s); nós ‹a g. resolveu ficar aqui mesmo›
gramática
nos usos informais da língua, é comum ocorrer a expressão a gente substituindo o pronome nós; a concordância é na 3ª p.s., mas, por associação com o significado do pronome, muitas vezes ela se faz pela primeira pessoa do plural, o que não corresponde à norma padrão: A gente foi à festa ontem (uso comum, principalmente informal); *A gente fomos à festa ontem (uso não correspondente à norma padrão)

E, via de regra, a concordância é com o gênero daquele que fala/escreve:

"A gente pode ser feio e ser bom. Isso é que importa." [2]
"A gente só é valorizada como mulher se formos mãe ou bonita, decorativa." [3]
"Quando a gente não é rico, acaba pensando nessas coisas. E, quando é preto, percebe logo que cada centavo é valioso, suado." [4]

Esse uso, inclusive, seria gramático desde pelo menos a primeira metade do século XX, Silveira Bueno (1938) [5]:

tal forma pronominal indefinida "exige a concordância com o gênero da pessoa que ela representa e não com o gênero dessa palavra". Assim, o homem haverá de dizer: "A gente ficou pasmado"; a mulher, porém, dirá: "A gente ficou pasmada".

Para os mais interessados, a pronominalização de "a gente" é descrita na tese [6] de Célia dos Santos Lopes, por exemplo (pg. 29, minha ênfase):

O contraste de gramaticalidade, nos exemplos abaixo, evidencia a mudança nos traços morfo-semânticos propostos para gente [+fem, φFEM] > a gente [φfem, αFEM]:
A) Toda a gente da minha aldeia ficou arrasada com as inundações.
B) *Toda a gente da minha aldeia ficou arrasado com as inundações.
C) A gente ficou arrasada com as inundações (eu + alguém/todo mundo, mas com referência exclusiva a mulheres).
D) A gente ficou arrasado com as inundações. (eu + alguém/todo mundo, referindo-se a um grupo misto e/ou a um grupo exclusivo de homens).
Por enquanto, pode-se dizer que a passagem da agramaticalidade de (B) para gramaticalidade de (D) deu-se pela perda da especificação do traço formal de gênero presente no substantivo e neutro nos pronomes pessoais “legítimos”:
[+fem] > [φfem]. Semanticamente a passagem do gênero neutro [φFEM] para o subespecificado [αFEM] também referenda a pronominalização da forma, na medida em que, como se viu, os pronomes pessoais “legítimos”, apesar de terem gênero formal zero, são subespecificados quanto ao gênero semântico.

Fontes
[1] Jessé Mourão (2023) "A concordância de número no português brasileiro: uma análise formal no quadro na gramática léxico-funcional", Fórum Linguístico v. 20 n. 3, DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.5007/1984-8412.2023.e76146
[2] Jaime, citado em: Míria Helen Ferreira de Souza, dissertação de mestrado "Literatura e formação humana: Nas entrelinhas das obras infantis de Clarice Lispector" (2014) Universidade do Estado do Rio Grande do Norte (UERN), Mossoró, pg. 150. (pdf)
[3] Lola Aronovich, citada em matéria de Paula Guimarães, 2019, Portal Catarinas: https://catarinas.info/a-gente-so-e-valorizada-como-mulher-se-for-mae-ou-decorativa/ (acessado em abril de 2024).
[4] El País Brasil, 2019, "“Racismo acontece de uma forma não dita. Aí reside a sordidez”. A dor do preconceito em primeira pessoa", G.D. de Oliveira, E.B.S. Silva, K.W.R. da Silva, https://brasil.elpais.com/politica/2019-11-27/racismo-acontece-de-uma-forma-nao-dita-ai-reside-a-sordidez-a-dor-do-preconceito-em-primeira-pessoa.html (acessado em abril de 2024).
[5] Bueno, Francisco da Silveira. Português pelo Rádio. São Paulo: Saraiva & Cia., 1938, p. 76. via José Maria da Costa, "A gente - Briga? Ficou sozinho?" Gramatigalhas, setembro de 2021, https://www.migalhas.com.br/coluna/gramatigalhas/350949/a-gente--briga-ficou-sozinho (acessado em abril de 2024). 
[6] Santos Lopes, Célia dos. "A inserção de “a gente” no quadro pronominal do português", Frankfurt a. M., Madrid: Vervuert Verlagsgesellschaft, 2003. https://doi.org/10.31819/9783865278494 (pdf)

Caro @stafusa, muito, muito grato pela aula!

Í could poke some holes in those arguments. For example: Assim, o homem haverá de dizer: "A gente ficou pasmado"; a mulher, porém, dirá: "A gente ficou pasmada". That assumes a gente is referring to we. A man could be referring to others, not to his own group...A gente que lá estava, for instance...

Se perguntares a um falante do português europeu ele dir-te-ia que a concordância devia ser no plural "a gente estamos" o Jessé Mourão está errado quando fala pelos europeus.

Obrigado pelo aviso, @bad_coder, adicionei uma advertência à resposta.

A gente fomos à festa ontem (uso não correspondente à norma padrão) Claro, fora do padrão além de soar muito mal. O Priberam explica claramente: a gente
• [Informal] Locução que corresponde semanticamente ao pronome pessoal nós, mas gramaticalmente a uma terceira pessoa do singular, e que designa o grupo em que se integra quem fala ou escreve (ex.: a gente vai chegar atrasada).
"gente", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/gente.

Eu não entendo o A, B, C, D. O A e B são iguais, e tambem o C e D.

Oi @Lambie , entre o A e B, assim como entre o C e D, a diferença está no "arrasada/o". Agora destaquei na resposta.

Agora sim. Obrigada. Em todo caso, eu nunca usaria o verbo no plural OU o masculino em ajetivos além de existirem todos os linguistas fazendo barulho. Eu por exemplo diria: A gente estava, todos nos, bem confusa. [haha] Cheers, luv.
